# Can't set data to an array in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray

I'm using Objective-C, I want to copy an array for another view controller and push it. Here is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"comment"]){
        commentViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.comments = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:comments];
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I got this in Xcode:

2015-12-06 16:27:45.802 net[1244:29117] -[UIViewController setComments:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8d34eb720
2015-12-06 16:27:45.807 net[1244:29117] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setComments:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff8d34eb720'

Someone can help me?

Comment: Check your storyboard.  It looks like the class for this view controller is UIViewController instead of your subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your destination view controller in the storyboard. And in the identity inspector make sure that your destination vc is your custom class as seen in the pic.

[image]